# Using keystrokes to control youtube play functions

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, media

I had this idea for a little app I want to make but I was wondering if it was possible to control the play/pause of a youtube video with an assignable keyboard key. Basically, what I want to do is have the user input a youtube url which will then create the look of an akia MPC where each video would represent a pad which could be controlled from the keyboard. I feel it most likely is possible but I am new to javascript so the API is a bit confusing to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Using the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) as a reference, you could do

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
       // user has pressed space
       player.pauseVideo();
   }
});
```

And do a bunch of other actions with the Youtube player as well